# jQuery UI droppable hitbox not updated if droppable element moves

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a collection of icons and a trash can. The trash can slides down when you pick up an element. The movements is triggered by the `dragstart` event.

The problem is that although the trash can element moves as expected, the hitbox stays in place (the draggable element can only be dropped on where the trash can *was*, not where it moved to.)

[This Fiddle illustrates the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/32H6J/4/) (Drag green box onto red box. Red box will turn blue when it thinks there is something dragged over it.)

This behavior occurs whether the animation is done in CSS or with jQuery.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$('.draggable')
    .draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.25,
        cursor: 'move',
        refreshPositions: true // forces recalculation of offsets
    })
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. Is the droppable documentation incomplete or was I just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: It's in draggable, which is counterintuitive, but they're deeply intertwined. The way to think of it is: "Should all offsets be re-evaluated during drag?"